# Min and max values for trace of product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, operator-theory

Suppose we have freely chosen two matrices A and B, which are 3$\times$3, real and symmetric i.e.:

$A= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda_3 \end{array} \right), $

$B= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \alpha_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \alpha_3 \end{array} \right). $

How we can estimate what is the range of values (min, max) for $\text{Tr}(AB)$? I start from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, where I land on
$-\sqrt{\text{Tr}(AA)\text{Tr}(BB)}\leq\text{Tr}(AB)\leq\sqrt{\text{Tr}(AA)\text{Tr}(BB)}$ and how to move next?

Comment: Isn't it $α_1λ_1+α_2λ_2+α_3λ_3$?

Comment: "freely chosen" $3 \times 3$, real and symmetric matrices need not be diagonal.

Comment: I'm not sure where you want to "move next". Both inequalities can be attained for certain concrete $A,B$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $AB= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\lambda_1 \alpha_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_2 \alpha_2& 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda_3\alpha_3 \end{array} \right),$

Hence $Tr(AB)=\lambda_1 \alpha_1+\lambda_2 \alpha_2+\lambda_3 \alpha_3$